# kd-tree BBF algorithm time complexity

Tags: kdtree

I hava 2000 points with 5000 dimensions , and I want to get the nearest neighbour.

Now I have some problems , could anybody give a answer.

1. People say , it works good with high dimensions. What's the time complexity ?
2. **@param max_nn_chks search is cut off after examining this many tree entries**

   After I read the algorithm, I wonder if I would get the wrong answer  when I set the max_nn_chks too low. If yes, then just tell me how to set this parameter, else give a reason, thanks.
3. Is the kdtree the best Data Structures for my data to get nearest neighbour?

Comment: Actually I only know people saying k-d-trees do **not** work well with high dimensional data.

Comment: But there is a BBF algorithm which change the search way that can work in high-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

1. The time complexity is basically the same as in restricted KD-Tree search plus some little time to maintain the priority queue. The restricted KD-Tree search algorithm needs to traverse the tree in its full depth (log2 of the point count) times the limit (maximum number of leaf nodes/points allowed to be visited).
2. Yes, you will get a wrong answer if the limit is too low. You can only measure fraction of true NN found versus number of leaf nodes searched. From this, you can determine your optimal value.
3. Usually a randomized kd-tree forest and hierarchical k-means tree perform best. [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/) provides a method to determine which algorithm to use (k-means vs randomized kd-tree forest) and sets the optimal parameters for you.

The structure of data also has a big impact. If you know there are clusters of points being close together, for example, you can group them in a single node of a tree (represent them by their centroid, for example) and speed up the search.

Another techniques such as visual words, PCA or random projections can be employed on the data. It's a quite active field of research.